# G is a group. Show that H is a sub-group of G if and only if $a * b^{-1} \in H, \forall a,b$

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

G is a group. Show that H is a sub-group of G if and only if $a * b^{-1} \in H, \forall a,b$

Well, if $H$ is a sub-group, we can say that $\exists a,b \in H$, thus $a * b \in H$, and then I can say that also $a*b^{-1} \in H$. I believe that what I said is true. If it is, how can I show that other way now? if $a * b^{-1} \in H, \forall a,b$ then H is a sub-group.

I believe the first one is to show that $a*b \in H$ which is true already. and I need to show that $\exists a^{-1} \in H$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

If you let $a$ be the identity element, what is $ab^{-1}$?

Comment: identity element is $a = e$?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS yes.

Comment: And everything else I've said is correct?

Comment: I just let $b$ be $b^{-1}$ for $\forall a,b | a*b \in H$

Comment: If $a*b^{-1} \in H$ I can say that $c = b^{-1}$ and then $\forall a,c \in H : a*c \in H$?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS Answer the question in the hint

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger If $a$ is the identity element, $ab^{-1}$ is $b^{-1}$. and then $b^{-1} \in H$. So it's the second one. but how can I prove the first one which means $a*b \in H$?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS Well, now you know that $b^{-1}$ is in the set (and, more generally, the inverse of any element in the set is in the set). So, what variables can we plug into $a*b^{-1}$ to make it equal to $a*b$ (knowing that we can only plug in things that we know are in $H$)?

Comment: $a * b^{-1} * a^{-1} = a * (a*b)^{-1} \in H \rightarrow a * a * b \in H \rightarrow a*b \in H$? @AkivaWeinberger

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS How did you get $a*(a*b)^{-1}\in H\rightarrow a*a*b\in H$? (The solution I'm looking for is much more simple)

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger If we found there's a $x^{-1} \in H$, so I believe $x \in H$ too

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS What's $x$ here? We found $a*(a*b)^{-1}\in H$, not $(a*a*b)^{-1}\in H$.

Comment: let $c^{-1} = (a * b)^{-1} \in H$, so $c = (a*b) \in H$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50146/discussion-between-ilan-aizelman-ws-and-akiva-weinberger).

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger thank you very much for helping